Unable to update searchsploit
Whenever I do searchsploit -u I get this error:
[i] Git pull'ing
POST git-upload-pack (317 bytes)
fatal: couldn't find remote ref master

[-] Git conflict
fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec. please use . instead if you meant to match all paths
fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec. please use . instead if you meant to match all paths
error: cannot open '.git/FETCH_HEAD': Permission denied
POST git-upload-pack (317 bytes)
fatal: couldn't find remote ref master

I tried doing  git config --global init.defaultBranch main but to no avail.
How to reproduce:
sudo pacman -S exploitdb
searchsploit -u

or
git clone https://gitlab.com/exploit-database/exploitdb.git /opt/exploit-database
ln -sf /opt/exploit-database/searchsploit /usr/local/bin/searchsploit
cp -n /opt/exploit-database/.searchsploit_rc ~/
searchsploit -u

I can't see where the solution is in this thread, or this or even this.

I run into the same problem after installing from Gitlab on an Ubuntu 24.04 installation. I checked the code of searchsploit and found that the repository is hardcoded twice as "master". On gitlab the repository is "main". To test I changed in the code to "main" and now it seems to work:
From https://gitlab.com/exploit-database/exploitdb-papers
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
 = [up to date]      main       -> upstream/main
Already up to date.

Maybe this helps you too.
